# Is there a way for Jenkins to automatically disable a node(take it offline) that has many failures within a specific time window?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

It happens that all jobs going to a certain node fail due to Java exception or machine related issue. Is there a way for Jenkins to automatically disable a node(take it offline) that has many failures within a specific time window?